# Отправка двух вариантов сообщения поочерёдно в боте телеграм. Python

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

Я полнейший профан в этом деле у которого просто чешутся руки. Не судите.
Идея такая: бот приветствует пользователя и отправляет ему реквизиты для оплаты доступа к закрытой группе. Таких реквизитов 2. Нужно чтобы бот поочерёдно выдавал разным пользователям разные реквизиты 50:50. Например:

---

```
Пользователь 1 получает "Реквизиты 1"; 
Пользователь 2 получает "Реквизиты 2"; 
Пользователь 3 получает "Реквизиты 1";
```

---

и так далее.
У меня за плечами один бот на кнопках, я слабо разбираюсь и понемногу вникаю. Надеюсь хотя бы на наводку. Заранее благодарю!

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Заведите глобальную переменную с индексом реквизитов и меняйте её по кругу. Решение универсальное, будет работать для любого числа реквизитов:

```py
requisites = ["Реквизиты 1", "Реквизиты 2"]
requisites_index = 0

def get_requisites():
    global requisites_index

    result = requisites[requisites_index]
    requisites_index = (requisites_index + 1) % len(requisites)
    return result

print(get_requisites())
print(get_requisites())
print(get_requisites())
```

Вывод:

```
Реквизиты 1
Реквизиты 2
Реквизиты 1
```

Либо с использованием стандартной библиотеки, результат такой же:

```py
from itertools import cycle

requisites = cycle(["Реквизиты 1", "Реквизиты 2"])

def get_requisites():
    return next(requisites)
```